# Glass Mapper Fluent Configuration - How to set Url Options on Link Field

Tags: glass-mapper

I am having trouble sorting out how to set Url options in fluent configuration. Basically, I want to do this:

```
[SitecoreField(UrlOptions=SitecoreInfoUrlOptions.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl)]
public virtual Link MyLink{get;set;}
```

But with fluent configuration. Im using V4.

Comment: Did my answer worked for you? If not please let me know, if yes please mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the following expression:

```
x.Field(x => x.MyLink).Configuration.UrlOptions = SitecoreInfoUrlOptions.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl;
```

And if you want to setup more options then you use the `&` operator:

```
x.Field(x => x.MyLink).Configuration.UrlOptions = SitecoreInfoUrlOptions.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl & SitecoreInfoUrlOptions.LanguageEmbeddingAlways;
```

I did not test yet, but it could work.